# Can I stream USB Audio from an iPhone to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ios, audio, raspberry-pi, hardware, mfi

The title pretty much says it all - Can I stream USB Audio from an iPhone to a Raspberry Pi?

So far, I have tried Volumio and Rune Audio which don't seem to have this capability.

I'm not sure if this is possible due to needing MFi or something of the sort.

Is there any way to do this? If there isn't, why? If there is, how can I do it?

EDIT: It's important for me to do this over USB as I am trying to find out if I can stream high-res audio (>= 24/48)

Answer (score 1):

If your phone browser supports `WebRTC` (Firefox does), then the easiest way is probably UV4L. [UV4L](https://www.linux-projects.org) provides several ways for streaming audio from a browser to the Raspberry (and viceversa, optionally) and requires no plug-in on the client side. Just install UV4L from the repository with the dummy driver, and run something like:

```
killall uv4l; uv4l --driver dummy --enable-server --server-option '--enable-webrtc-video=no' --server-option '--enable-webrtc-audio=no' --server-option '--webrtc-receive-video=no' --server-option '--webrtc-receive-audio=yes' --auto-video_nr
```

The above will run an `uv4l` instance with a streaming server listening to the default port 8080. Open the browser at `http://yourrpi:8080/stream/webrtc` and click on the "Call" green button at the bottom to select the audio device and send audio to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: See my edit. I need to do it over USB. It sounds like what you're describing is over the network -- Is that correct?

Comment: No, I did not notice that requirement. Have you added it after the original question?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry. It's in the edit.